# ngx-slider positioning of ceil value (dynamic)

Tags: angular, slider

[image]

I'm trying to get the placement of the 'infinity sign' consistent across screens. seems like the offset is being set inside the slider component code. the icon is conditional based on if the high slider is at the ceil value. Since the offset is calculated in the component after the ceil value is set, I'm not sure on how to consistenly place the icon.

using npm's `ngx-slider` [link to slider page](https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new options object.
So after you define the options object, you can redefine it as a new options object like this.

this.Options = {
floor: 1,
ceil: 2000
};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).